# Replace symbol ';' in a string

Tags: c++, string, replace

I am doing my first project, and I have one question.

I have a string: `"73+77=;98;2;150;63"`.
I want to replace the first semicolon with `"A)"`, the second semicolon with `"B)"`, the third semicolon with `"C)"`, and the forth semicolon with `"D)"`.

I have tried this, but it does not work how I want. Could you help?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string s="95*35=;3325;32;4;23",a,b,c,d;
    int q,e,i,m=0;
    for(i=0;i<s.size();i++)
    {
        if(s[i]==';')
        {
            e++;
            q=i;
            if(e==1){s[i]='A';}
            if(e==2){s[i]='B';}
            if(e==3){s[i]='C';}
            if(e==4){s[i]='D';}
            a=s.substr(0,q);
        }
    }
    cout<<a;
}
```

I want the result to be like this: `"95*35=A)3325 B)32 C)4 D)23"`, but my code writes everything together.

Comment: Generally speaking, it would be easier to create a new string instead of modifying one in place. Not clear what you want exactly. You should post both the expected output and your current output. I guess you will have to insert some `\n` inside the string. Just a guess.

Comment: Not sure what your problem is... You mean you want to add in the spaces and parentheses as well? Try the `std::string::replace` method then. Edit: Or `std::string::insert`

Comment: "_some variables maybe extra(sorry for this)_" - don't be - just edit the question and remove them so you don't have to be sorry.

Comment: You should initialize `e` (ex: `e = 0`), else you have undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I would write it differently. I'd toss that for-loop and do something like this:

```
string output = "";
for (const char c: s) {
    if (c != ':') {
        output += c;
    }
    else {
        output += 'A' + e++;
        output += ')';
    }
}
```

When you're done, output is what you care about. I haven't actually run this code, but I'd do it like this, not trying to fiddle with the individual characters.

Comment: I would take this one step further by adding a call to `output.reserve()` before the loop, so that the `+=` concatenations don't have to keep reallocating memory. You know the input size and the desired output size up front, so only 1 allocation is needed.